# How to create semi-transparent image using imagemagick

Tags: png, transparency, imagemagick

I have a hex (i.e. #FF0000) color and want to generate 50% transparent 50x50 image using imagemagick from command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to figure out something similar when I was working with [CSS 3 and RGBA](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/).

```
convert -size 50x50  xc:'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)' red_0.5_pixel.png
```